# (Unity Multiplayer) Как спавнить пулю на клиенте и отправлять координаты пули серверу?

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте!
У меня имеется скрипт PlayerShoot:
Это один из его методов:

```
[Command]
void CmdShoot()
{
    // Create the Bullet from the Bullet Prefab
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(
        bulletPref,
        bulletSpawn.position,
        bulletSpawn.rotation);

    // Add velocity to the bullet
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 700;

    //// Spawn the bullet on the Clients
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);

    // Destroy the bullet after 2 seconds
    Destroy(bullet, 2.0f);
}
```

Вызов данного метода происходит при нажатии на ЛКМ.
Все работает отлично за исключением одного НО, спавн пули происходит на сервере и передается на клиент(как я понял) и когда я подключаюсь к серверу(удаленно в другом городе) то при стрельбе с клиента пуля спавнится с задержкой после выстрела и если я буду ходить(персонажем) то пуля будет спавниться вне оружия.

[image: Спавн пули в движении]

это пример как спавниться пуля при ходьбе вправо влево. Мне нужно сделать так: пуля должна спавниться на клиенте и передаваться серверу. Я пытался сделать так:

```
void Shoot()
{
    // Create the Bullet from the Bullet Prefab
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(
        bulletPref,
        bulletSpawn.position,
        bulletSpawn.rotation);

    // Add velocity to the bullet
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 700;

    //// Spawn the bullet on the Clients
    // NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
   CmdSpawn(bullet);
    // Destroy the bullet after 2 seconds
    Destroy(bullet, 2.0f);
}

[Command]
void CmdSpawn(GameObject bullet)
{
    //Spawn the bullet on the Clients
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
}
```

Но выдает вот такую ошибку:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так чтобы пуля спавнилась на клиенте и отправлялась серверу(ее местоположение) как это происходит с игроком.

P.S. Большое спасибо всем!

Comment: Никто не подскажет??(